# What are these devices mounted on old fashioned domestic electric trunking?

Tags: electrical

[image: Some kind of old-fangled electric thingummibob]

[image: An older version made of ceramic]

Location: India

Estimated date-range for installation of the objects under enquiry 1920 - 1960

Just what the title states. The trunking exhibits several boards with similar thingummibob mounted upon them. What are these things (name)? What purpose do they serve?

Comment: Location UK? (guess based on "trunking") I certainly hope this is not live, given that there appear to be exposed terminals on two of the "whatevers" - I'd speculate that there might be something under the covers on the non-exposed ones that is missing from the exposed ones, perhaps something (protective?) that would need to vent smoke when it blew up, thus the 4 holes... But I'm speculating from the other side of the Atlantic.

Comment: @Ecnerwal: Location British India :) I've updated the description with the location, and approximate periof when these devices may have been installed. The wiring is old-fashioned insulation oil-cloth/guttapercha. p.s. The wiring is live - I removed the covers on two ... and they promptly went walkabout. Those two covers that remain are obstinate in maintaining their embrace of the receptacles.

Comment: Live with what voltage?

Comment: Possibly related: http://www.plugsocketmuseum.nl/Italian_3hd.html See #14.

Comment: Are they in all rooms of the house, assuming this is a house? If not what room are they in? Are the covers metal or plastic?

Comment: @isherwood: Domestic supply in india 250@50Hz.

Comment: @PlatinumGoose: The body is bakelite. The metal strips are brass

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **What are these things (name)?**

They are sometimes called "fuse-pots".

> **What purpose do they serve?**

They each contain two contacts which are bridged by a thin piece of fuse wire which connects the electrical supply to wiring to a specific individual circuit. They prevent your house burning down in the all-too-likely event that there is a malfunction in some equally ancient and uncared for wiring, switch, lampholder, wiring or appliance.

---

That is an antique fuseboard

See [Architectural Salvage](https://picclick.co.uk/Antique-Electrical-Fuse-Boardwagoodingbrightonarchitectual-Salvage-272545684796.html), Brighton, England.

[image: Antique round ceramic fusees on a wooden board]
[image: inside of a fuse]

Yours seem to be a later Bakelite version rather than ceramic.

The individual holders may have been called fuse-pots.

Note that some old fuse-boards had fuses on both live and neutral

---

They look rather similar to earlier 19th century fuse holders of the sort used in the 1890s.

- Early Edison Fuse block in article [Early Electrical Lighting in Homes
  By Steve O'Bannon](http://www.rexophone.com/?p=1175)
  [image]
- ["Very old Electrical Fuses", Alamy](http://l7.alamy.com/zooms/4c8487524fcc4f9a815d1fa02873db12/very-old-electrical-fuses-box-d72x05.jpg)
- ["Germany, very old fusebox", Alamy](http://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-germany-antique-old-dusty-fuse-box-58081589.html)

However these earlier ones are all screw-in fuses following an Edison design I think.

---

> **Any idea how to open the cover if it refuses to? WD-40 threw in the towel**

Please don't spray flammable fluids onto live 240V electrical installations.(my can of WD40 says "caution flammable" on the front)

I'd be surprised if there was anyone still alive with experience of dealing with these things. At least, not in my part of the world.

If I were in your shoes, my immediate priorities would be

- Find and replace the protective covers.
- Warn any adult occupants of this building not to touch any part of this panel.
- Prevent children getting access to this area of the building.
- Pay a qualified electrician to supply and install a modern consumer-unit (main panel) where the electrical supply enters the building. Have that electrician fit miniature circuit breakers (MCBs) and residual current devices (RCDs or GFCIs) or combined protective devices (RCBOs etc).
- Take these antique fuse panels out of service and replace them with a properly protected junction box or similar.
- Consider getting the wiring in the building removed and replaced. At least get it tested.

Having isolated the electrical supply to that panel, I would fabricate a removal tool by screwing four long screws part way into a wooden block and cutting off the heads to make *short* studs that fit those four holes. A small amount of penetrating oil might help but I suspect the chances of it making a difference are low. I'd have a fire extinguisher handy. Double check that power is off before going anywhere near that panel.

Comment: Perfect! There are a few ceramic pots too. I'll take the liberty of including a photograph of it in the description above.

Comment: Any idea how to open the cover if it refuses to? WD-40 threw in the towel

Comment: @Everyone: answer updated.